# How much time do I need to learn LabVIEW

Tags: labview

I know that this question is too abstract. But. How much time do i need to learn LabVIEW to become average LabVIEW developer? For example, if I  buy good book about LabVIEW and have 8 hours per day (on my work) dedicated to LabVIEW learning how many days i will spend on LabVIEW learning? Could you please provide example from your own experience. More information about me that can be helpful: I'm a developer and know c\c++\python and a little bit of java languages.

Comment: I endorse this question. I too want to know how to start with LabView efficiently as an experienced developer. What I would like is a series of small challenges to practice and reinforce my understanding as I work through the tutorials and white papers. Can anyone suggest a suitable publicly available resource?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like Swinders said, it might depend a lot on your sensibilities. I have seen people who had a really hard time migrating to the data flow concept. It's a different paradigm from the classic text-based languages and some people can't easily think in these concepts.

If you get past that hurdle, you'll find that the IDE handles a lot of the annoying things you used to take care of for you (things such as syntax and memory allocation). This allows you to become productive very quickly.

It doesn't mean, however, that your level would be high. One potential pit you should try hard to avoid is casting your existing experience onto LV. The most common example is probably local variables. This may be shocking to people coming from a text-based world, but LV does not have variables, per-se. Unfortunately, it does have elements called variables and people migrating from C who find them jump on them and use them as they would use variables in C, leading to LV code which looks like C code and is bad code (at least in LV).

If you do manage to work around this, I would guess you would become better than the global average in less than a month and better than most professional developers after creating three projects you would later look at and say "what the hell was I thinking?".

I never took any of the NI courses (although I understand some of the advanced architecture ones are pretty good), but I would suggest you also spend some time in some of the online communities (such as LAVA or the NI forums) and look at some of the examples and discussions there. There's a lot of material about best practices, design patterns, etc., which would allow you to become a more professional developer.

Above all, do not abandon your current professional conduct. If you have a structured process for designing and developing software, you already have a leg up on the majority of LV programmers. Just make sure you adapt and keep using such a process.

Answer (score 5):

I started with no commercial programming experience (I have always programmed for fun) and followed an on-line tutorial to pick up the basics of LabVIEW. Within a week I was able to understand existing code and could develop a small application.

It is hard to give an estimate on how long it would take to become an 'average' LabVIEW developer as this depends on what you mean by 'average'. One thing to consider is how easy you are able to think in terms of data flow rather than procedural languages. If you can pick up new programming languages quickly then this will help.

Would you be the only person using LabVIEW or are there others at your place of work that could mentor you? You may also find that there are user groups operating near you which I would recommend (check the [NI website](http://decibel.ni.com/content/community/zone/labviewusergroups) or contact your local NI office).

There is then the experience that you will need to gain to allow you to produce good LabVIEW code. I was lucky to be able to attend the National Instruments training courses a few years ago which I think helped me but only by using it have I become an 'average' LabVIEW developer.

Answer (score 5):

I'd say a few weeks or most with devoting the majority of your work time to it.  I had a similar background to you when I started to develop in LabVIEW.  The hardest part was adapting to the lack of variables.  There are local variables, but it's not what you're used to at all.  Additionally, their functions, called Virtual Instruments (VIs) can have multiple inputs and outputs, similar to how Python can handle n-tuples.

I will warn you, their array handling features are terrible.  A lot of general concepts you might be used to are difficult to implement.  My mantra when working with the language is it makes hard things easy and easy things hard.  There are also a lot of "gotchas" in the language set, especially with their DAQmx function.  I'm not sure what you're planning on developing and their Real-Time module has it's own issues as well, different issues from the main language set.

I would definitely spend some time on NI's [website](http://www.ni.com/) and read as many [whitepapers](http://www.ni.com/innovations-library/white-papers/) as you can, especially about good design practices, [here](http://search.ni.com/nisearch/app/main/p/bot/no/ap/tech/lang/en/pg/1/sn/catnav:wp/q/%22design%20patterns%22/) and [here](http://search.ni.com/nisearch/app/main/p/bot/no/ap/tech/lang/en/pg/1/sn/catnav:wp/q/coding%20practices/).  Learn their State Machine ([here](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/3024/en/) or [here](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/2926/en/)) and [Producer/Consumer](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/3023/en/) pattern well, that's the backbone of many applications you'll be writing.

Good luck, it will make your head spin for a while.

Answer (score 2):

We are using LabVIEW to create test software for our factory test systems. In the past years I have already trained some beginners to understand LabVIEW. I would say it depends on how good you are at learning new concepts. I have trained some to be able to produce standalone applications using the queued message handler concept, doing dynamic GUIs and using hardware drivers within about 3 weeks. Unfortunately there were others aswell that were only able to learn half of that within half a year.

The most important thing in my opinion is the learning source. Having an experienced LabVIEW user that can guide you is the best option. If there is no one not available I would recommend Youtube Tutorials combined with the shipped LabVIEW examples.
The LabVIEW core tutorials are not very handy in my opinion. Those are quite boring and far from what you really need to get started.

Answer (score 1):

There are some excellent resources to help you get started. If your employer can afford training, you can get started pretty quickly by taking a week of training run by National Instruments. The NI website also has an outstanding developer community that is highly responsive to questions even from novice developers. But I would say that the key to being comfortable with the idioms and style of the language is just plain old practice that you get by solving problems using LabVIEW on a regular basis.

You will find eventually that there is the question of hardware and instruments. Labview is really all about data acquisition-- either through NI's DAQ hardware or through traditional GPIB instruments, or through 3rd party api's (activeX, .NET assemblies). If you're using LabVIEW, you're probably interfacing to hardware of some type. This can get really challenging with complex instruments and measurements. If you're getting started, I would recommend making sure that you have unlimited access to at least some of the hardware you'll be working with. In other words, make sure that your manager understands that you need a lot of access to the hardware in order to get good at developing with it.